# Python Turtle Window on Top

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

When I run the code below using Idle for Python 3.6, the turtle screen appears underneath the Idle screens, which is very unsatisfying.

If I omit the input request for the background colour and just use `wn.bgcolor("blue")` the window appears at the front, as I want.

I've looked at the docs and found `turtle.setup(width=_CFG["width"], height=_CFG["height"], startx=_CFG["leftright"], starty=_CFG["topbottom"])` but there doesn't appear to be any kind of z-index parameter.

Any suggestions please?

```
import turtle

bg_colour = input("Enter the desired background colour: ")
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor(bg_colour)      # Set the window background color
wn.title("Hello, Tess!")      # Set the window title

tess = turtle.Turtle()
tess.color("blue")            # Tell tess to change her color
tess.pensize(3)               # Tell tess to set her pen width

tess.forward(50)
tess.left(120)
tess.forward(50)

wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give the following a try -- the `rootwindow.call()` tkinter incantations are from the turtle demo code where they move the turtle graphics window above the terminal window:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

bg_colour = input("Enter the desired background colour: ")

wn = Screen()

rootwindow = wn.getcanvas().winfo_toplevel()
rootwindow.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')
rootwindow.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '0')

wn.bgcolor(bg_colour)  # Set the window background color
wn.title("Hello, Tess!")  # Set the window title

tess = Turtle()
tess.color("blue")  # Tell tess to change her color
tess.pensize(3)  # Tell tess to set her pen width

tess.forward(50)
tess.left(120)
tess.forward(50)

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm, I'm just sad not to understand what I'm doing...